# JS Slide div class not working - simple issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a button that on click will slide a div named "inner". The fiddle is here: Updated - http://jsfiddle.net/NfXTY/1/

The problem is somewhere on this line `var $marginLefty = $('.inner');`.

I also wanted to know how I can start the animation the other way around, so when you click it the first time it slides in and clicking again will slide it back out.

Comment: you are giving `margin-left: 0` where it is already 0

Comment: @ArunPJohny: That doesn't quite answer the problem I am having :/

Comment: that is why it was added as a comment not an answer

Comment: @ArunPJohny: :) Ok so I have removed it but still no difference :/

Comment: The problem is related to the absolute positioning + something

Comment: Haha thanks for that. What is the "+ something"? I've updated the questions with the new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NfXTY/1/ just need to get it starting not displayed

Comment: still looking into that something

Comment: fiddle is acting crazy here... little slow

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ff2Cw/1/

Comment: Never mind, I've answered my own question. I'll paste the answer

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't do what I've asked, I don't quite get what you have done :D - see my answer - http://jsfiddle.net/NfXTY/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ff2Cw/2 was my second option... but by the time you said you had the answer....

Comment: but the first positioning you had a problem

Comment: see my answer below.... it works with `position: absolute`

Answer (score 0):

`.inner` needed a start point of `margin-left:350px;`

Answer (score 0):

I updated your Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/NfXTY/2/ . You were missing `+'px'` at `$marginLefty.outerWidth()`. It should be `$marginLefty.outerWidth()+'px'`.

Comment: Also, note that you don't need the `$` symbol to declare variables in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks @PHPglue! Also, instead of doing a `$(this).next();` what was it again to select the specific class? ie: If I wanted that to animate the class of "inner" but inner wasn't able to be chained because it is somewhere else on the document.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using absolution positioning... because of that the margin-left is not working.... use `left` instead

```
<div class="inner" style="left: 350px;">Animate this element's margin-left style property</div>
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slidemarginleft button').click(function () {
        var $marginLefty = $(this).next();
        $marginLefty.animate({
            left: parseInt($marginLefty.css('left'), 10) == 0 ? $marginLefty.outerWidth() : 0
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ff2Cw/)

Comment: Thanks Arun! Now how can I use `var $marginLefty = $(.inner);` instead of `var $marginLefty = $(this).next();` as the inner div won't be able to be chained - it will be sitting down the bottom of the page. Thanks!

Comment: @DT.DTDG use `var $marginLefty = $('.inner');`

Answer (score 0):

The inner class is not correct.
If you want to set margin-left you should set **left** is 0, rather than right:0, 
so .inner class should be

```
.slide .inner {
        background-color: #44CC55;
        bottom: 0;
        color: #333333;
        height: 36px;
        left: 0;
        padding: 6px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 338px;
    }
```

Or keep setting the right value, you should set the margin-right value to slide from right to left, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#slidemarginleft button').click(function() {
        var $marginLefty = $(this).next();
        $marginLefty.animate({
          marginRight: parseInt($marginLefty.css('marginRight'),10) == 0 ?
            $marginLefty.outerWidth() :
            0
        });
      });
    });
```

Fiddle link: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamght/NfXTY/5/)